# usestate react hook for functional component always rerender whole component while using setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am using usestate reacthooks in functional component my problem whenever I am setting new state 
the whole components  rerender and my state is back to initial state

```
const Feeds = (props) => {
  // remove the intial element that is of no use...
  const baseUrl = props.api
  let nextPage = props.feeds.nextPage;
  let products = props.feeds.products.filter(el => !el.isSilder);
  console.log('intial products ....', products);

  let [feeds,setFeeds] = useState(products);
  let waitForNextTrench = false;  

  const feedRequestData =  {
    filterData: {
      catArray:[],
      assured:"0",
      gender:"NA",
      cityId:"NA"
    },
    pageNo: nextPage
  };
  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener("scroll",handleScroll);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  },[])

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const loadMore = document.getElementById("loadMore");
        if (loadMore && shared.isElementVisible(loadMore)) {
      loadMoreFeeds();
        }
  };

  const loadMoreFeeds = () => {
    if (nextPage != 1) {
      return null;
    }
    if (waitForNextTrench) {
      return null;
    }
    waitForNextTrench = true // make the function wait till the data is 
  renderd properly

    feedsApi.userFeeds(baseUrl+'/product/userFeeds',feedRequestData).then(data=>{
      if (data.success) {
        const updatedFeeds = products.concat(data.products.filter(el => !el.isSilder));
        setFeeds(updatedFeeds);


        console.log('this is the feeds', feeds.length);

        nextPage = data.nextPage;
        waitForNextTrench = false;
      }else { 
        // lets handle error later
        waitForNextTrench = true;
      }
    }).catch(err=>{
        // let me handle error later    
    })    
  }
  const headObject = {
    title:'Buy Sell fashion / electronics / tickets / books / online – coutloot.com", "Best platform to sell | buy products online, women\'s and men\'s clothes, ethnic, mobile phones, beauty/makeup, books, footwear, bags, electronics, shows, events tickets online in india',
    desc : "",
    keywords:""
  }
   return(
       <Fragment>
            <Header headobject={headObject}/>
            <div className={`d-flex f22 ${styles.feedheader}`}> 
              <a className="icon-hamberger_menu py-2-5 pl-3 text-pink1"></a>
              <div className="d-flex align-items-center text-black pl-3 w67">
                        <span className="f16 font-bold px-2"> Filters </span>  
                        <img src="/assets/images/go-forward-arrow.png" alt="" height="15px" width="15px" />
                    </div>
              <div className="d-flex">
                <div className="text-center py-2 px-2 r-icon">
                    <span className="icon-search ml-auto" ></span>
                </div>
                <div className="text-center py-2 px-2 r-icon">
                    <a className="icon-wishlist" ></a>
                </div>
                <div className="text-center py-2 px-2 r-icon position-relative">
                    <a className="icon-shopping-cart" ></a>
                    <span className={`${styles.cartCount}`}> 1</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <Layout >
              {
                <FeedController feeds={feeds} />

              }              
            </Layout>
            <LoadMore />
       </Fragment>
   )
}
```

I want to push new array on the setting state but it is rendering every time and state goes to its initial values

initial value is array list and I want to concact new array list that I get from API load more feeds is called when user scrolls to the bottom of screen

now  i have given full component code

I want only update the dom not the whole function

Comment: Can you share you whole component code?

Comment: @AhmedAbdulrahman it is very lengthy code i have just shared small snippets which is causing main problem

Comment: Its important to know how is loadMoreFeeds called. Also have you written a useEffect that calls setFeeds?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  when screen scrolls till down

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri please check now

Comment: @AhmedAbdulrahman please do check now

Comment: React components rerender when you change its state or its props, and the DOM you return is part of the Component (It's part of the function). you cannot "just update the dom not the whole function". You should lift the feeds state and update it in the parent component since I see you're passing the feeds as a prop. I suggest you check the official docs.

Comment: @alex i am using nextjs server side rendering  the props i am passing through getStaticProps() method and this is the main component

Comment: @RajRana I took some more time and answered your question. I didn't test it, but I'm pretty sure the issue is what I say in my answer. Don't hesitate to bring any questions up.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the function in [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), it allows to handle component lifecycle methods

```
useEffect(()=>{
  feedsApi.userFeeds(baseUrl+'/product/userFeeds',feedRequestData).then(data=>{
    if (data.success) {
      const updatedFeeds = products.concat(data.products.filter(el => !el.isSilder));
      setFeeds(updatedFeeds);

      nextPage = data.nextPage;
      waitForNextTrench = false;

    }else { 
      // lets handle error later
      waitForNextTrench = true;
    }
  }).catch(err=>{
    // let me handle error later    
  })    
}, [])
```

Comment: hi  reacts hooks are only allowed inside the react functional component

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your code more in-depth and I think I found the issue: You are relying on `products` to update the state, but `products` is a new variable on each render. The reason to use `useState` is that `React` will ensure that this state is kept between re-renders. I hope it fixes your issue.

```js
const Feeds = props => {
  // remove the intial element that is of no use...
  const baseUrl = props.api;
  let nextPage = props.feeds.nextPage;
  let products = props.feeds.products.filter(el => !el.isSilder);
  console.log("intial products ....", products);

  let [feeds, setFeeds] = useState(products);

  let waitForNextTrench = false;

  const feedRequestData = {
     filterData: {
       catArray: [],
       assured: "0",
       gender: "NA",
       cityId: "NA"
     },
     pageNo: nextPage
   };

  const loadMoreFeeds = () => {
    if (nextPage === 1 || !waitForNextTrench) {
      waitForNextTrench = true; // make the function wait till the data is renderd properly

      feedsApi
        .userFeeds(baseUrl + "/product/userFeeds", feedRequestData)
        .then(data => {
          if (data.success) {
            const updatedFeeds = feeds.concat(  // This was the important change!!!
              data.products.filter(el => !el.isSilder)
            );
            setFeeds(updatedFeeds);

            console.log("this is the feeds", feeds.length);

            nextPage = data.nextPage;
            waitForNextTrench = false;
          } else {
            // lets handle error later
            waitForNextTrench = true;
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // let me handle error later
        });
    }
  };

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const loadMore = document.getElementById("loadMore");
    if (loadMore && shared.isElementVisible(loadMore)) {
      loadMoreFeeds();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  const headObject = {
    title:
      "Buy Sell fashion / electronics / tickets / books / online – coutloot.com\", \"Best platform to sell | buy products online, women's and men's clothes, ethnic, mobile phones, beauty/makeup, books, footwear, bags, electronics, shows, events tickets online in india",
    desc: "",
    keywords: ""
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header headobject={headObject} />
      <div className={`d-flex f22 ${styles.feedheader}`}>
        <a className="icon-hamberger_menu py-2-5 pl-3 text-pink1"></a>
        <div className="d-flex align-items-center text-black pl-3 w67">
          <span className="f16 font-bold px-2"> Filters </span>
          <img
            src="/assets/images/go-forward-arrow.png"
            alt=""
            height="15px"
            width="15px"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="d-flex">
          <div className="text-center py-2 px-2 r-icon">
            <span className="icon-search ml-auto"></span>
          </div>
          <div className="text-center py-2 px-2 r-icon">
            <a className="icon-wishlist"></a>
          </div>
          <div className="text-center py-2 px-2 r-icon position-relative">
            <a className="icon-shopping-cart"></a>
            <span className={`${styles.cartCount}`}> 1</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Layout>{<FeedController feeds={feeds} />}</Layout>
      <LoadMore />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Also, I recommend you use `eslint` and check the docs again, they always bring insight.